# Sign in Failed on Heroku and Firebase React js & express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, express, backend

I am using **Heroku and firebase** for backend & frontend Database from MONGODB
When I sign-up its store data in database correctly but in **Sign-in** its doesn not get data from database .....Please tell me what I am doing incorrect

**FRONT-END**

```
 const res = await fetch(http://wu.herokuapp.com/signin", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
       
        "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password,
      }),
    });
```

**BACK-END**

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://wu.firebase/",  
  methods: "GET,HEAD,POST,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS",
  credentials: true,              
  allowedHeaders: "Origin,Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With",

}
 router.use(cors({origin:true,credentials: true}));

router.options('*', cors())

router.use(express.json());
router.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));


router.post("/signin",cors(corsOptions), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let token;
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!email || !password) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Plz Filled the data" });
    }
    const userLogin = await User.findOne({ email: email });


    if (userLogin) {
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, userLogin.password);
      token = await userLogin.generateAuthToken();
        res.cookie("jwtoken", token, {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() +  100000000),
        httpOnly: false,
       
      },
```

Comment: What issue are you facing ? Can you explain what is not working as expected?

Comment: my sign up is successful from database but in sign in it is not getting any data or no jwt token is created there